Set column width for Pandas Styler and save to excel format
I want to highlight the data that equal 0 in green, else highlighted in red. And then export in Excel format.
However, the Column Width of the exported excel did not fit for the data length. I have to manually adjust the column width after exported.
I had to used "set_table_styles' but it not work.
My code
df = df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: #00FF00" if x == 0 else "" if pd.isnull(x) else "background-color: #FF0000")

df = df.set_table_styles({'A': [{'selector': '', 'props': 'width: 300px'}]})

with pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx') as writer:
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data', index=False)


I hope the export excel can auto-fit for the length of the data.
| Column A |     Column B    |
| -------- | ----------------|
| Cell 1   | Cell xxxxxxxxxxx|
| Cell 3   | Cell xxxxxx     |

where is the rest of a code for a minimal reproducible example
